# Fine grained transformation vs coarse grained transformations

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

Could anyone please explain the difference between fine grained transformation vs coarse grained transformations in context of Spark? I was reading the paper on RDDs (https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~matei/papers/2012/nsdi_spark.pdf) and not very clear how coarse gained transformation provides fault tolerance in an effective way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A fine grained update would be an update to one record in a database whereas coarse grained is generally functional operators (like used in spark) for example map, reduce, flatMap, join. Spark's model takes advantage of this because once it saves your small DAG of operations (small compared to the data you are processing) it can use that to recompute as long as the original data is still there. With fine grained updates you cannot recompute because saving the updates could potentially cost as much as saving the data itself, basically if you update each record out of billions separately you have to save the information to compute each update, whereas with coarse grained you can save one function that updates a billion records. Clearly though this comes at the cost of not being as flexible as a fine grained model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped. What are the different ways in which I can make spark into a fine grained model? Basically I want to build a DAG that works at the cell level instead of a table level. Once a cell is updated I want to trigger other cell level updates in multiple tables based on the DAG. Let me know if you have inputs.